Does “Eurasianism” (as a term) feature in the rhetoric of many AfD figures?
According to the NYT

Mr. Dugin also popularized terms like “Eurasianism” that now feature in the rhetoric of many AfD figures.

However, the English Wikipedia article on the AfD doesn't even once mention this term. So, is true that the term features literally "in the rhetoric of many AfD figures"?
I do not doubt that they want US troops gone from Germany, and closer ties with Russia and China etc. I'm interested if they self-describe those positions (or something related) as "Eurasianism".

It seems "AfD" refers to a German political party.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_for_Germany

If they use this term I would assume it does not relate to foreign troope or foreign policy but rather to immigration/ population. Something like Eurasian=white=good and non-Eurasian (meaning mostly Arabic/ Turkish) = bad. But I don't know whether they use the term Eurasian to peddle that story.

For people trying to research this question: The term that German proponents of the concept would use is probably "Eurasismus", not "Eurasianismus" or similar.
